# Ruby on Rails: Validate CSV file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

Having followed the RailsCast on importing CSV (http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel), I am trying to validate that the file being uploaded is a CSV file.

I have used the gem `csv_validator` to do so, as documented here https://github.com/mattfordham/csv_validator

And so my model looks like this:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessor :my_csv_file
  validates :my_csv_file, :csv => true

  def self.to_csv(options = {})
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
        csv << column_names
        all.each do |contact|
            csv << contact.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
        end
    end
  end
    def self.import(file, user)
    allowed_attributes = ["firstname","surname","email","user_id","created_at","updated_at", "title"]
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        contact = find_by_email_and_user_id(row["email"], user) || new
        contact.user_id = user
        contact.attributes = row.to_hash.select { |k,v| allowed_attributes.include? k }
        contact.save!
    end
  end
end
```

But my system still allows me to select to import non-CSV files (such as .xls), and I receive the resulting error: `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`.

Can someone please tell me why and how to resolve this?

Please note that I am using Rails 4.2.6

Comment: You could check the file's extension before trying to import it: `file.path.split('.').last.to_s.downcase == 'csv'`

Comment: @MrYoshiji thanks for your comment, I would also want to validate the  data in certain columns as well though, which this gem (should) allow me to do

Comment: this gem allows you to retrieve the data in the columns, it is your part to make the logic to "validate the data" in the column. I can post an answer if you want some hints on where to begin

Comment: Ok, can you please post an answer

Answer (score 6):

You can create a new class, let's say `ContactCsvRowValidator`:

```
class ContactCsvRowValidator

  def initialize(row)
    @row = row.with_indifferent_access # allows you to use either row[:a] and row['a']
    @errors = []
  end

  def validate_fields
    if @row['firstname'].blank?
      @errors << 'Firstname cannot be empty'
    end

    # etc.
  end

  def errors
    @errors.join('. ')
  end
end
```

And then use it like this:

```
# contact.rb
def self.import(file, user)
  allowed_attributes = ["firstname","surname","email","user_id","created_at","updated_at", "title"]
  if file.path.split('.').last.to_s.downcase != 'csv'
    some_method_which_handle_the_fact_the_file_is_not_csv!
  end
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    row_validator = ContactCsvRowValidator.new(row)
    errors = row_validator.errors
    if errors.present?
      some_method_to_handle_invaid_row!(row)
      return
    end

    # other logic
  end
end
```

This pattern can easily be modified to fit your needs. For example, if you need to have import on several different models, you could create a base CsvRowValidator to provide basic methods such as `validate_fields`, `initialize` and `errors`. Then, you could create a class inheriting from this CsvRowValidator for each model you want, having its own validations implemented.