# Spreadsheet import validation with persisted import model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, import, ruby-on-rails-5

I've been struggling the last couple days trying to create an import process for users to upload CSV/Excel files. I have been trying to imitate the process done in this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast) episode. However, my requirements are a bit more complex so I have been trying to modify what has been done there but I have hit a wall when it comes to enforcing model validation to ensure against any bad data.

I am trying to use [Roo](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo) to allow my users the ability to upload CSV or Excel files. I also would like to **save** the `OrderImport` model with the uploaded spreadsheet and some other information for historical reference and what not.

**Models**

```
property.rb
  has_many :owners
  has_many :orders

owner.rb
  belongs_to :property

order.rb
  belongs_to :property
  has_many :owners, through: :property

order_import.rb
  #no assications
  #uses paperclip to save the attached file
```

**Order Import process in `order_import.rb`**

```
def load_imported_orders(file, cid, uid) #loads file from controller along with client_id and user_id for use in order creation
  spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  order_imports = (2..spreadsheet.last_row).map do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    property = row["address"]
    propparse = import_address_parse(property) #to parse submitted address
    newprop = if Property.exists?(propparse)
                Property.find_by(propparse)
              else
                Property.new(propparse)
              end
    owner = row["owner"]
    newowner = Owner.find_or_initialize_by(name: owner)
    newprop.owners << newowner #creates new property/owner association
    neworder = Order.new(property_id: newprop.id,
                         client_id: cid,
                         task: "Property Report",
                         submitted_by: uid)
    neworder
    newprop
    newowner
  end
  @imported_orders = order_imports
end

def import_address_parse(property)
  address = StreetAddress::US.parse(property)
  if address.blank?
    new_blank_prop = { address1: nil,
                       city: nil,
                       state: nil,
                       zipcode: nil }
  else
    new_prop = { address1: address.to_s(:line1),
                 city: address.city,
                 state: address.state_name,
                 zipcode: address.postal_code}
  end
end

def save
  if @imported_orders.map(&:valid?).all?
    @imported_orders.each(&:save!)
    true
  else
    @imported_orders.each_with_index do |order, index|
      if order.instance_of?(Property) #needed to reduce the amount of errors shown on the form
        errors.add :base, "Row #{index+2}: Please re-check the Address of your Property."
      else
        order.errors.full_messages.each do |message| #shows any errors not related to property
          errors.add :base, "Row #{index+2}: #{message} | #{order}"
        end
      end
    end
    false
  end
end
```

**`order_import controller`**

```
def create
  @order_import = OrderImport.new(params[:order_import_params])
  @order_import.load_imported_orders(params[:order_import][:document], params[:order_import][:client_id], params[:order_import][:submitted_by])
  if @order_import.save
    redirect_to external_client_orders_path(current_user.client_id), notice: "Imported Orders successfully."
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

So as you can see, the `load_imported_orders()` method gets called from the controller and parses the spreadsheet. Then a `property & owner` are found (if they happen to exist already) or initialized and then an `order` is initialized from the items in that row. (I've tried using something like a `:before_create` filter in my `OrderImport` model but I have no idea how these different guides are opening files passed through `OrderImport.new(params[:order_import_params])` without the model being saved first - and of course I don't want to save unless everything imports correctly).

The purpose for the `import_address_parse` method is because the address is submitted as one line (555 test rd, testington, tt, 55555) but is comprised of `address1, city, state, zipcode` in my database. The [StreetAddress gem](https://github.com/street-address-rb/street-address) will return `nil` if it cannot parse the entire address string so I have put that catch in there to return a nil object in hopes to fail the `property` model validations when `Property.new` is initialized with all nil values in those fields.

**The problems**

For some reason the `Property` validation does not fail on its own, I am  only alerted when `owners` go to be saved and associated to the `new property` in the `save` method. `Property.exists?()` with all nil attributes still loads a `property` for some reason instead of initializing `Property.new` and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

The `order` validation fails because a no `property.id` exists since the `new property` hasn't been saved yet, which I understand, but I'm not sure how create the `Order` association/creation from the `save` method (i.e. outside of the `load_import_orders` method which is parsing the import data).

I think my understanding of the entire validation side of importing bulk records is **fundamentally wrong**, especially since I cannot get the `OrderImport` record to save correctly even when adding `create_or_update` ([Rails API docs)](https://apidock.com/rails/v1.2.6/ActiveRecord/Base/save) to my `save` method, which overwrites the default rails save method for the model.

This may be easier than I'm making it out to be but I would consider myself to still be an amateur Rails developer (having taught myself everything through tutorials, SO posts, guides/articles) and am diving into what I think is complex methodology so if someone could take the time to assist me with refining this process so that I can achieve what my goal is here and attain a deeper understanding of rails in general.

Added caveat, if I change all the `find_or_initialize_by / new` calls to `create!` and ONLY use data I know would pass all validations then this process works as intended but we all know thats not realistic in a real-world environment. I think since that part works its throwing me off from re-engineering this a bit (it's not the end of the world if using built in rails `CSV.parse` instead of Roo is the way to go but I'd like to provide the option of being able to import from excel but its not a necessary one).

Thank you to anyone who takes the time to break this down and help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after posting this question with no responses, I decided to brush up on my Ruby IRB skills to work my way through the process and analyze the data every step of the way. 
After much trial and error, I've finally completed this task!

To provide a brief overview of my final process:

Following the methodology of the answer in this SO question, [Ruby on Rails: Validate CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38856987/7286108), I decided to

1. Break out the validations into its own Ruby class.
2. Using [Roo's `Parse` method](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo), I passed each row as a Hash to `OrderImportValidator.new()`
3. Pass the `row[:property]` pair through my `import_address_parse` method.
4. Instantiate both `row[:property] && row[:owner]` using `.find_or_initialize_by` method to their respective models.
5. Pair up each `:property` and `:owner` objects into a hash within a `OrderImportValidator` instance variable (`@order_objects`) and allow access to it from my `OrderImport` model via a method (very similar to how the `@errors` is returned in the linked SO CSV question).
6. Verify validation of all values (instantiated objects) in the returned hash.
7. If all were good, then I called `save` on each, create the correct associations, and appropriate `order` for each pair.
8. Added a custom `validate :import_error_check, on: :create` to my `OrderImport` model.
9. Run through `each.with_index`, check if errors exist, clear the errors on the object and add my custom message to `errors[:base]` of `Order Import` with their appropriate `index` and display them on the page.

Pretty pumped I figured it out and have furthered my knowledge of data manipulation, objects, and ruby syntax. Maybe the outline of my process will help someone else one day. Cheers.